# Android Studio emulator is very slow on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, android-studio, emulation, haxm

I have a problem with the Android emulator64-x86 on Mac OS X 10.11.2 comes with Android Studio 1.5. The startup task a long time a the GUI doesn't response. The task manager shows that the emulator needs up to 100% CPU. I found many question with the same scope, but nothing solve my problem.

I have already installed HAXM (latest version 6.0.1). The emulator says

```
emulator: GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: HAX (version 3) is installed and usable.
```

I'm confused version 3, but I have installed version 6.0.1.

In the console I got this messages

```
08.03.16 20:08:14,000 kernel[0]: Kext com.intel.kext.intelhaxm not found for unload request.
08.03.16 20:08:19,000 kernel[0]: haxm_error: -------- HAXM release 6.0.1 --------
08.03.16 20:08:19,000 kernel[0]: haxm_error: This log collects running status of HAXM driver.
08.03.16 20:08:19,000 kernel[0]: haxm: Unknown ioctl 
08.03.16 21:30:02,000 kernel[0]: haxm: Unknown ioctl 
08.03.16 21:30:17,000 kernel[0]: haxm: Unknown ioctl 
08.03.16 21:30:17,000 kernel[0]: haxm_error: Unsupport VM IOCTL 20007461
08.03.16 21:30:17,000 kernel[0]: haxm_error: Unknow vcpu ioctl 20007461
08.03.16 21:30:27,000 kernel[0]: haxm_error: 
08.03.16 21:30:27,000 kernel[0]: ...........hax_teardown_vm
08.03.16 21:30:47,000 kernel[0]: haxm_error: 
08.03.16 21:30:47,000 kernel[0]: ...........hax_teardown_vm
```

I remember that on a Windows PC I installed the emulator, I have to switch on the HAXM support in the BIOS. In the readme file I found this known issue.

```
1. XD/VT check with "-c" option will only show the CPU capability. it cannot tell if XD/VT is disabled by BIOS
```

The -c options returns

```
VT support -- Yes
NX support -- Yes
```

I'm not very familiar with the Mac system architecture. But my understand is that the Mac haven't any BIOS. Is there a menu which I can switch on the VT/NX support?

I start the emulator via terminal with the argument "-show-kernel". It takes 5 seconds from first kernal message to the message "start boot animation". But the next message comes 40 to 50 seconds later.

At the moment the emulator is complete unusable for me.

Thank you for your help

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows 10 with an Intel Core 2 Q6600 CPU. I wonder if HAXM just doesn't make any difference for certain CPUs? What CPU does your Mac have?

Comment: Facing the very same problem, but targeting Android 7.0. Were you able to find any solution to this problem? (besides switching to Genymotion.. which I haven't tried)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Genymotion as your emulator.

[Download Here - Genymotion](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjWvd-S8bLLAhWDkY4KHWY0DWsQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.genymotion.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFe_83y8u2kkTCsdtEigYhL4Wskrw&sig2=2eQeUTzRNmWd3JmiFVmFvQ)